# How to draw a border around a image texture in threejs?

Tags: three.js

I am building an image editor in threejs. There can be more than one images in the screen at a time and if a particular image is clicked a border should be added to the clicked image. Is there a builtin feature in threejs that i can use?

Comment: There is some ongoing discussion at github about a similar topic (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16029). It's not possible to add an outline or border effect to PNG sprites right now but maybe there will be an example that shows how to do this with shaders.